# How to code process_state variable which reruns each time process commences?

Tags: arduino, sensor, c++, flow-sensor

I am making a bottle filling machine. I am using the [YF-S201 water flow sensor](http://www.mantech.co.za/datasheets/products/yf-s201_sea.pdf) to do the same and a 600ltr/min pump. While according to the sensor datasheet I should get the 750ml at 369 pulses, but my bottle was barely filled by counting to just 369 so I calibrated for my 750ml bottle and started counting to 1910. But upon subsequent button presses it over flows. Below is the advice I received to sort out the same, but I don't know how this advice would take shape in code. Can somebody alter my below code to help this out. Thanks.

Advice:
"when you press the button the seond time it starts the process all over. You avoid it by adding a new variable, call it process_state, which starts at zero. When the button is pushed, you check the value of process_state. If it is zero, you set it to some other value and begin operation. If process_state is not zero, you simply ignore buttonpush. When the loop total reaches your limit, you set process_control to zero and close out the loop"

```
volatile int flow_frequency; // Measures flow sensor pulses
// Calculated litres/hour
 float vol = 0.0,l_minute;
unsigned char flowsensor = 2; // Sensor Input
unsigned long currentTime;
unsigned long cloopTime;


int SolenoidPumpPin=4;

// constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin = 9;     // the number of the pushbutton pin

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void flow () // Interrupt function
{
   flow_frequency++;
}


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(SolenoidPumpPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SolenoidPumpPin, HIGH); //Switch Solenoid ON
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(flowsensor, INPUT);
   digitalWrite(flowsensor, HIGH); 
   Serial.begin(9600);

attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(flowsensor), flow, RISING); // Setup Interrupt
currentTime = millis();
   cloopTime = currentTime;


}

void loop() 
{



  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH)
  {
    currentTime = millis();
   // Every second, calculate and print litres/hour
   if(currentTime >= (cloopTime + 1000))
   {
      cloopTime = currentTime; // Updates cloopTime
      // Pulse frequency (Hz) = 7.5Q, Q is flow rate in L/min.
      l_minute = (flow_frequency / 7.5); // (Pulse frequency x 60 min) / 7.5Q = flowrate 
in L/hour
      /*lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Rate: ");
      lcd.print(l_minute);
      lcd.print(" L/M");*/
      l_minute = l_minute/60;
      //lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      vol = vol +l_minute;
      /*lcd.print("Vol:");
      lcd.print(vol);
      lcd.print(" L");*/
      flow_frequency = 0; // Reset Counter
      float Vollume = (l_minute*cloopTime)/1000;
      //Serial.print(l_minute, DEC); // Print litres/hour
      //Serial.println(" L/Sec");

    while(flow_frequency<=1910)
    {
      digitalWrite(SolenoidPumpPin, LOW);
      Serial.println(Vollume);
      flow_frequency++;

    }
   }

    else {
      /*lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Rate: ");
      lcd.print( flow_frequency );
      lcd.print(" L/M");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("Vol:");
      lcd.print(vol);
      lcd.print(" L");*/
    }
    digitalWrite(SolenoidPumpPin, HIGH);








  } 


}
```

Comment: `But upon subsequent button presses it over flows` ... what does that mean? ... did you start with an empty bottle?

Comment: what is the desired behavior?

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: @jsotola Yes I started with an empty bottle. Like the first time it fills fine, but the second time it tries to fill more. If I switch off the power and switch it on again and then press the button, then it fills fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough framework for you to expand on (not tested).

It shows how to use a flag variable to control action.

Action is dependent on the state of a single variable, not on the state of a switch, or a sensor, or a timer.

The state of the variable can be controlled by as many things as you like.

````cpp
void flow() {
  flow_frequency--;
  if (flow_frequency < 0) flow_frequency = 0;
}

void emergencyStop() {                           // just an example
  flow_frequency = 0;                            // send a message to loop()
}


void setup() {
    
  flow_frequency = 0;

}

void loop() {

  if (flow_frequency <= 0) {

    digitalWrite(SolenoidPumpPin, HIGH);         // turn off valve

    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
      flow_frequency = 1910;                     // set flag 
    }
  }

  else { 

    digitalWrite(SolenoidPumpPin, LOW);          // turn on valve

  }  
  
  
  // do calculation and display routines here

}

```
````